# python scapy module not recogonizing IP

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7.9 and scapy (2.2.0)

When interacting with the scapy or Python interactive shells directly and sniff packets, I can normally use the IP to extract the source and destination IPs, but when trying to put the code into a .py file and then run:

```
python file.py
```

It says:

```
NameError: global name 'IP' is not defined
```

file.py

```
from scapy.all import *

def main():
    sniffed=sniff(iface='eth0',count=10)
    print (sniffed[1][IP].src)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `sniff` returns a packet list. 
The second element you query (using `[1]`) is a packet. Print it using `packet.sprintf('%.time% %-15s,IP.src% -> %-15s,IP.dst% %IP.chksum% "
"%03xr,IP.proto% %r,TCP.flags%')`.

Also look in the [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf).

Comment: Why didn't it raise `NameError: name 'IP' is not defined`?